# Android xml shape drawable

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

I want to draw xml layout shape above showing image android.please help       me

Comment: Try to post what you have done so far and what problem you are facing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459916/how-to-make-an-imageview-with-rounded-corners check it

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:color="#80000000"
        android:width="0.5dp"
        />
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="32dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="32dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all try to show your progress or what you have tried so far and where you have got stuck.

Secondly for your question, use below code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="10dp"
        android:top="10dp">

    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black" /> //change your desired color
//use can set your desired size to make curve 
        <corners
            android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp" 
            android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="10dp" 
            android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Create this drawable and use in your xml

Answer (score 1):

If you want only left two corners to be curved. Then just set `bottomRightRadius` & `topRightRadius` to `0dp`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/color_Transport_Grey" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your shape (fab.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="@color/main_light_extreme">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/main_light_extreme" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/main_normal" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**Your image with shape background (ImageButton):**

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/fab"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" <!-- your need this -->
        android:elevation="12dp" />
```

**Result (Note: ripple works only android api >= 21 Lollipop):**

[image: Simple float action button.]

*Image above drawable shape :D*